# error Cannot find module using webpack

Tags: css, webpack, ecmascript-6

I am using webpack and ecmascript-6, when I try to import my css file I got the error:

```
Cannot find module './css/mystyle.css'.
```

This is my folder sctructure:

[image]

This is my webpack configuration:

[image]

And I try to import as:
[image]

Comment: Is the code compiled inside the `src` folder or somewhere else?

Comment: You can use `code blocks` and do not need to share screen shots of your code ^.^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem in this link:

[Solution](https://medium.com/@sapegin/css-modules-with-typescript-and-webpack-6b221ebe5f10)